# How can the DHCP routers option work if it's my own IP address?

Tags: dhcp

I'm setting up a T-Mobile USB 4G data modem on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm not making sense of the DHCP lease that T-Mobile gives me. Specifically, the value of the "option routers" is identical to the address I'm being assigned. Is this some weird convention or some corner case of DHCP that I'm not aware of? By trying the SIM card on an android phone I discovered that it uses the ".1" address on the subnet as the default route. I manually added that to my linux config and it works great. But it doesn't happen automatically, which is a pain each time I get a new IP address assigned. Any suggestions or clues?

Here is a sample lease I receive:

```
lease {
  interface "wwan0";
  fixed-address 25.10.135.136;        <=== my address
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 25.10.135.136;       <=== huh? how can this be my address?
  option dhcp-lease-time 259200;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 10.177.0.34,10.166.71.132;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 25.10.135.253;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 129600;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 226800;
  option netbios-name-servers 0.0.0.0,0.0.0.0;
  renew 3 2014/12/10 16:33:54;
  rebind 4 2014/12/11 21:46:20;
  expire 5 2014/12/12 06:46:20;
}

# ip route
default via 25.10.135.1 dev wwan0     <=== added manually
25.10.135.0/24 dev wwan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 25.10.135.136
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.4

# traceroute www.yahoo.com
traceroute to www.yahoo.com (206.190.36.105), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.170.229.176 (10.170.229.176)  1884.846 ms  1908.830 ms  1955.671 ms
 2  10.162.181.53 (10.162.181.53)  1997.994 ms  1997.769 ms  1997.494 ms
 3  10.170.229.194 (10.170.229.194)  1998.892 ms  1997.052 ms  1998.222 ms
 4  10.177.69.77 (10.177.69.77)  2017.923 ms  2017.681 ms  2026.235 ms
 5  10.177.66.50 (10.177.66.50)  2027.135 ms  2036.931 ms  2034.545 ms
 6  ae51.bar2.LasVegas1.Level3.net (205.129.18.73)  2036.366 ms  169.899 ms  147.560 ms
 7  ae-14-51.car4.Seattle1.Level3.net (4.69.147.134)  134.786 ms  86.866 ms  86.280 ms
... etc ...
```

Ifconfig shows:

```
wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:5d:54:11:01:07
          inet addr:25.10.135.136  Bcast:25.10.135.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::345d:54ff:fe11:107/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:288 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:7256 (7.2 KB)  TX bytes:25992 (25.9 KB)
```

Comment: Are you sure it’s not a PPP connection?

Comment: Great question... The device is set-up automatically by a sierra_net driver (this is a sierra wireless 4G modem). The ifconfig doesn't reveal anything about PPP, which I would expect it to (I'm adding the output to the question). How would you determine whether it's PPP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a network administrator, but this looks like a bug in modem configuration. Furthermore, I wouldn't be surprised if it works on Windows, which may have a recovery scenario for such cases, and that's why qa haven't caught it.

In your case I would have run `ip neigh show` to see which machines your system had talked too and what their IPs are to obtain real address of the router. Another alternative is to use wireshark or map, but it's more involved.